Build Issue for Lineage (21.0) gsi x86_64 eng. Redundant artifact path entries
I followed the instructions for building Lineage OS 21.0 for emulator/avd (from https://wiki.lineageos.org/emulator) and when building (after calling "mka" command) I receive the following error:
[ 99% 1311/1312] finishing legacy Make module parsing ...
FAILED:
build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:31: warning: vendor/lineage/build/target/product/lineage_gsi_x86_64.mk includes redundant artifact path requirement allowed list entries.
Offending entries:
system/framework/oat/%/org.lineageos.platform.odex
system/framework/oat/%/org.lineageos.platform.vdex
system/framework/oat/%@service-compos.jar@classes.odex
system/framework/oat/%@service-compos.jar@classes.vdex
In file included from build/make/core/main.mk:1433:
build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:31: error: Build failed.
10:47:43 ckati failed with: exit status 1

I know that there are workarounds to this such as excluding the offending entries or altogether disabling PRODUCT_ENFORCE_ARTIFACT_PATH_REQUIREMENTS but I fear that these are heavy-handed and will introduce failures to the build. This error seems to indicate that something is wrong but I am not sure as to what.
Any help/information is appreciated.
Thank you

I had made a mistake. The proper target (as explained in the linked wiki) is sdk_phone_x86_64, not gsi_x86_64
